# Where are the source-codes contained in the IDL-directory?

Tags: idl-programming-language

can someone tell me, where i can find the source-codes contained in the IDL-Directory.

In IDL one can run "demo". Under "Math and Statistics" -> "Math and Statistics Demo", there is as an example a polynomial fit. Where is the source-code for this polynomial fit contained within the idl directory?

best regards

Comment: You have a wrong tag, this is not about `Interface Description Language`.

Answer (score 0):

So your answer has several parts. You can find the "demo" source code in your IDL installation, inside examples/demo/demosrc. If you want the source code to the actual polynomial fit routines, those will either be in source code inside the "lib" directory, or they might be written in C code for speed. The documentation will tell you if it is written in pro code.

For pro code routines, once you've compiled the routine, you can always use the "routine_filepath" command to find the source code location. Hope this helps!